# Prepending the size of a byte array to the byte array

Tags: clojure

I have a byte array, for example:

```
(def g (byte-array (map byte [0 1 2 3])))
```

How do I get the size of it and how do I prepend this size to the g byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prepending part can be done like this (probably not the best solution):

```
(def g (byte-array (apply #(cons (byte (count %)) %) [(map byte [0 1 2 3])])))
```

It returns:

```
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I think that you should use `(alength g)` for the length of a Java array.

Of course if your byte array is longer than 255 you will have problems with adding the length as a single byte.

Comment: Maybe `(byte-array (cons (-> g count byte) g))`? Or `(->> (cons (count g) g) (map byte) byte-array)` if you need to cast everything?

Comment: May be like this: `(def g (->> [0 1 2 3] (#(cons (count %) %)) (map byte) (byte-array)))`

Answer (score 3):

`alength` will get you the size.

You'd have to make a new array to prepend it. Here goes:

```
(def g' (let [len (alength g)
              bs (byte-array (inc len))]
          (do (System/arraycopy g (int 0) bs (int 1) len)
              (aset bs (int 0) len)
              bs)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean about prepending the size,  but you can get the size using `count`

```
user=> (def g (byte-array (map byte [0 1 2 3])))
#'user/g
user=> (count g)
4
```

Comment: Thanks I mean to add the size to the beginning of the array. For google protocol buffers.